# How can I get documents inside a subcollection in every document in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get all the documents inside the subcollection "userPosts" in Firebase Firestore with JavaScript? You can see my database structure in the pictures below.

Here is what I have tried:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    var postRef = database.collection('posts').doc().collection('userPosts');

    postRef.get().then(snapshot => {
        setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
    })

    const posts = document.querySelector('.posts');

    const setupPosts = (data) => {

        let html = '';
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const post = doc.data();

            console.log(post)

            const li = `
            <li>
                <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
                <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
            </li>
            `;
            html += li
        })

        posts.innerHTML = html;

    }
})
```

What this code should do is to get the documents in the subcollection "userPosts". And it should go into every document in the collection "posts" and then go into "userPosts" and get every document in that subcollection.

[First collection "posts"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfdjd.png)

[Subcollection "userPosts"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lro6O.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you show what you tried already, or why the code from this documentation doesn't work for you? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: I have now added the code I tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).  This will give you all the documents in all subcollections named "userPosts":

```
const query = database.collectionGroup("userPosts")
query.get().then(querySnapshot => { ... })
```

Comment: Been struggling for hours with nested promises and loops (not working), this saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

This line makes no sense:

```
var postRef = database.collection('posts').doc().collection('userPosts');
```

The `database.collection('posts').doc()` creates a reference to a new, non-existing doc in the `posts` collection. Since you then its `userPosts` subcollection, this is of course going to not exist/be empty.

---

If you want to get the `userPosts` subcollection for your `user` argument, and you store the users based on their UID, then that'd be:

```
var postRef = database.collection('posts').doc(user.uid).collection('userPosts');
```

Comment: But I don't want to get a specific document with the UID as the docID, I want to get every document and then go into the subcollection, if you understand.